# Router.push not working as expected in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs,Right now i am getting correct data after refesh page instead of "onclick" so for solve this issue i am trying to use "router.push" but not working means "updated data" not displaying ,displaying only after refresh page,How can i do this ?
Here is my current code

```
const Post = ({ post, blogs }) => {
    const routersss = useRouter();
    const getnewdata = (e,slugtype) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        var spath=slugtype;
        routersss.push(spath, undefined, { shallow: true })
       }
}
return(
<>
<div className="img-content new-data" onClick={(e) => getnewdata(e,blog.slug)}> // passing slug/url 
    //further html(blog module)
<div>
</>
)
```

Comment: can you explain what you want?

Comment: @PriyenMehta Right now i am getting correct data afterclick , so i just want to reload page (not refresh) so data will display correctly,means just like refresh page

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might works.

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: i dont want to reload page , i just want to refresh data ( thats why i used router.push)

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom v5 or v6?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to use `useHistory` hook

```js
const history = useHistory()
history.push(YOUR_URL)
```